# For loop excluding some DataFrame rows based on a specified value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, jupyter-notebook

I have folder with 10000+ files, which contain the data of 10 variables (X1, X2, ..., X10).

The name of the files is just File1.json, File2.json etc.

I need to create a dataframe for each variable, i.e. 10 DataFrames.

**INPUT**

- VARIABLES= [X1, X2, ..., X10]
- FILES= [File1.json, File2.json, ... File14347.json]

**Desired output**

- Dataframe of X1, X2, ..., X10

I am doing the following

```
for i in range(0, len(VARIABLES)):
    %reset_selective -f "^DATA$"
    DATA=pd.DataFrame()
    Data_name=VARIABLES[i]
    print(Data_name)
    for ii in range(0, len(FILES)):

        file_name1='Directory/'
        file_name2= FILES[ii]
        file_name=file_name1+file_name2
        with open(file_name, 'r') as fer:
             data1 = json.load(fer)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'count': data1})

        Var_namei=df['count']['consistname']
        if Var_namei==Data_name:
            #create Dataframe
```

The code works fine for the first Variable, as I do not know which files contains the data of X1.

**However, from the second iteration there is no point in reopening every single file in order to find the data of X2. 
Similarly, I should open only the files of X10 when I reach the last iteration.**

*I want to avoid opening/considering files whose data have been already used as an input to a DataFrame, e.g. File2 contains values of X1, therefore I don't want to open again File2 when I'm looking for the values of X2, X3, etc*

I've tried to add

```
k.iloc[ii,i]= ii
```

where k is a dataframe of zeros size (File, VAriable) after the if condition, in order to put a 1 in the i column and ii rows when a file ii of the variable i is open. In this way, I can skip such ii rows files during next for iterations.
But, I am unable to access the k values during the for loop.

any suggestion?
thank you

Comment: Could you please indent the first for loop of your code and provide an example of the input and the desired result?

Comment: Does each file contain a single value or multiple values?

Comment: Multiple values, from 100 to 50000 values. The amount of data of each file is not known beforehand, i.e. I need to open the files and extract all the values to know their amount

Comment: Did you try reading each file into a DataFrame with pd.read_json and then do the processing based on columns?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the files are nested json, therefore I have the name of the variable at "first level", then the data and subvariables at second level, which I get as `json.loads(First_Json_variable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Your code can be much simpler if refactoring a little.

```py
file_name1='Directory/'
FileDATA={}
for file_name2 in FILES:
    file_name=file_name1+file_name2
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fer:
        data1 = json.load(fer)
    if data1['consistname'] in VARIABLES:
        # Save the data1 object to FileDATA
        # Assuming that every element in VARIABLES is unique
        Data_name=data1['consistname']
        FileDATA[Data_name] = data1

for Data_name in VARIABLES:
    data1 = FileDATA[Data_name]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'count': data1})
    # create Dataframe
```

The first loop goes through all files once and save the data which corresponds to a variable of `[X1, X2, ..., X10]` in a dictionary `FileDATA`. Then you can loop over the variables to process the data.

After removing unnecessary lines,

```py
FileDATA={}
for file_name2 in FILES:
    with open('Directory/' + file_name2, 'r') as fer:
        data1 = json.load(fer)
    if data1['consistname'] in VARIABLES:
        FileDATA[data1['consistname']] = data1

for Data_name in VARIABLES:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'count': FileDATA[Data_name]})
    # create Dataframe
```

Comment: I have also managed to remove a file from the directory when it has been already considered.